# Como escribir una fecha en Python y verificarla?

Tags: python, date

Disculpen las repetidas preguntas pero recien comienzo a programar! :)
Como  coloco una fecha en Python?Y luego como la puedo verificar?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con verificar la hora?

Comment: Hola Iván, ¿Con "colocar" te refieres a que sea ingresada por el usuario vía `input`? ¿Con que formato ("31/4/2018", "31/04/18", "31-4-2018", etc)? ¿Qué quieres decir con "verificarla"? ¿Ver si es una fecha válida o no? Mírate el módulo `datetime` y en especial [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!!!